# EditText phone number format text watcher but with different country codes from a spinner on pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I'm currently trying to implement this:

[image]

I've already done the spinner part, though the phone `EditText`, I'm not so sure about how to make a TextWatcher for it.

I have 2 options:

1. I use:

   `phoneNumberET.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());`
2. Or, I use

`phoneNumberET.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("countryCode"));`

Both of these have their flaws. In #1, it won't properly format since the country code isn't found in the **`EditText`**, but in the **`Spinner`**.

In #2 I can only use this in API level 21 and above.

So, is there a solution that can let me format the phone number properly with a country code from the spinner **and** be available from below API 21?

Answer (score 0):

Earlier platform levels don't have an API for phone number formatting in other regions, you'll need to bundle it with your app. You can use a library such as [googlei18n/libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) (or a fork like [libphonenumber-android](https://github.com/MichaelRocks/libphonenumber-android)) to provide the data and formatting, then add a [TextWatcher](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/issues/1113#issuecomment-279008059) for integration with Android.